# How to load a website inside a air for android application (flash)

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash-cs6, air-android

I need to load my own website in a air for **android** application (stage WebView) using actionScript(3.0).Is it possible ?

I use following code but isn't work inside my application.

```
navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://www.adobe.com"), "_blank");
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com! It is expected to put some effort into solving a problem on your own. Show the code you have tried so far, so you can get more specific advice. Learn more on how stackoverflow works by taking the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.media.StageWebView;
import flash.geom.Rectangle;



var webView: StageWebView = new StageWebView();


webView.stage = this.stage;
webView.viewPort = new Rectangle(0, 0, stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight);
webView.loadURL("http://www.adobe.com");
```